# Omniture rest 1.4 API returns bad request

Tags: java, rest, restful-architecture, restful-url, adobe-analytics

On using report.get method of omniture 1.4 rest API, returns 400 bad request, even though the report delivery is completed

`exceptions.HTTPRequestFailedException: {ERROR_BODY={"error":"delivery_complete","error_description":"Delivery complete","error_uri":null}`

Is this expected?

Comment: Are you still getting this error? If so, can you post the API request code?

Comment: Yes, still facing the issue. I was using this library https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/analytics-java-library